# cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int?>' to expected argument type 'Int' swift

Tags: swiftui, qr-code

I have some error when i am writing a qr code generator and it said **cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int?>' to expected argument type 'Int**, i don't why it have error and i don't know how to solve it, does any expert know how to solve it?

My Code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct QRCode: View {
  @State private Second: Int?
  @State var navigated = false

  let seconds: [Int] = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
  
  var body: some View {
          NavigationView{
               VStack{
                  Picker(selection: $Second, label: Text("Select Seconds"))
                     {
                        Text(""),tag(nil as Int?)
                        Foreach(seconds, id:\.description) {
                        second in Text("\(second)").tag(second as Int?)
                      }
                    }
                 }
                   NavigationLink(destination: Generate(second: Second), isActive: self.navigated)             <-  Error in this part
                  {
                      Text("Complete")
                  }
}
struct QRCode_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
          QRCode()
    }
}

struct Generate: View {
   var second: Int

   let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
   let const = CIContext()

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView{
               Image(uiImage: GenerateSecond(seconds: second))
             }
        }
   func GenerateSecond(seconds: Int)-> UIImage {
        let sec = "\(second)"
        let com = sec.data(using: .utf8)
        filter.setValue(com, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
              return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
              }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

I Have hightlighted in the code to show where have error, it is in the NavigationLink part has error

Comment: There are many compilation errors here. Please consider taking the time for format your code, take care of typo issues (`Foreach` for example) and follow Swift conventions (capitalize type names, not variable names).

Comment: @jnpdx do you have any example?

Comment: An example of what? I have given you some concrete suggestions.